# Same SQL statement giving different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I selected rows from a view (the where clauses in the view are on static data).
If I run the SQL below I get the same results everytime.
I expect the recordsIds to be the same and in the same order, but they are totally different!

I'm using SQL SEVER 2012.
Can anyone explain why this results are different?

[image: Screen dump of sql server]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The `order by` clause tells it to sort them numerically, and the screenshot posted appears to indicate that the results come back in order.

Comment: He/she is wondering why *the same five* `RecordId`s aren't returned in each case

Comment: Is it possible that someone played a trick on you? Is it possible that someone created two columns: `Recordld` and `RecordId`, the first one is with lower case L, and another one is Capital i?

Comment: Your data has been changed since your first query I reckon...

Comment: Is this a view using `select top 5`?

Comment: Must be a bug in the database :)

Comment: @armandino - the database is fine :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We would have to see the definition of the view.  Let's say the view were defined as

```
select top 5 * from MyTable
```

That view could return 5 different rows every time it is called. 
Or perhaps the view is designed to return randomly selected rows.

Comment: I wrote the view, it's not designed to return different rows, however the view doesn't have an order by on it either. But you are correct there is a TOP 5 on the view, does this mean that the order is different when selecting different things?

Comment: I put an order by in the view, now its working the way I want it to.

Comment: Just to be clear, a TOP query without an order by has no guarantee of which rows will be returned.

Comment: Without an order by, the results can never be garantueed the same.